# SQL Select Records ONLY When a Column Value Is In More Than Once

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server, I am trying to select only the records where a column's value is in there more than once, This may seem a bit of an odd request but I can't seem to figure it out, I have tried using HAVING clauses but had no luck..

I want to be able to only select records that have the ACCOUNT in there more than once, So for example:

```
ACCOUNT | PAYDATE
-------------------
B066    | 15
B066    | OUTSTAND
B027    | OUTSTAND  <--- **SHOULD NOT BE IN THE SELECT**
B039    | 09
B039    | OUTSTAND
B052    | 09
B052    | 15
B052    | OUTSTAND
```

BO27 should NOT show in my select, and the rest of the ACCOUNTS should.

here is my start and end of the Stored Procedure:

```
Select * from (

*** SELECTS ARE HERE ***

                ) X where O_STAND <> 0.0000 
        group by X.ACCOUNT, X.ACCT_NAME , X.DAYS_CR, X.PAYDATE, X.O_STAND 
        order by X.ACCOUNT
```

I have been struggling with this for a while, any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What columns do you need to return?  Just the Account? If it is in there multiple times do you need to return all of them or just distinct account?

Comment: I am returning all of them, I only showed 2 columns in the Question for the sake of Example. I will want to return all the column values that are in there more than once. I only DO NOT want to show records if the Value is in there ONLY once.

Comment: @DJONES tried `having count(X.ACCOUNT) > 1`? I bet not :-)

Comment: @DJONES do you have a unique identifier for a row?  or what columns together make a row unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could replace the first string with

```
Select *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT) cnt FROM (
```

and then wrap your query as subquery once more

```
SELECT cols FROM ( query ) q WHERE cnt>1
```

Comment: This is perfect, Exactly what I needed, I'm sure the other answers work just as good but this did the trick nicely.

Comment: @DJONES sadly, users these days looking only for something that "do the work", but not learn anything or try to make it nice and simple. `group by` with `having` condition will be faster and easier to read.

Comment: @krtek I tried using the HAVING COUNT (X.ACCOUNT) > 1 a few days ago but it didn't work the way I hoped it to, Using Dmitry's count column allows me to get a handle on the number of ACCOUNTS per type in my Report, which I will also be able to use for further implementations, You are right in your point, but I am not in that category :)

Comment: @DJONES maybe, because you were grouping by multiple columns? You will get to this problem again, even with this solution. Or your question wasn't clear :-)

Comment: @krtek I was hoping to solve my problem with a HAVING clause originally as I wasn't aware that you could do "COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT)", using this will help my plans further down the line without a doubt. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `having` clause is for solving exactly this kind of tasks. Basically, it's like `where`, but allows to filter not only by column values, but also by aggregate functions' results:

```
declare @t table (
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    AccountId varchar(20)
);

insert into @t (AccountId)
values
    ('B001'),
    ('B002'),
    ('B015'),
    ('B015'),
    ('B002');

-- Get all rows for which AccountId value is encountered more than once in the table
select *
from @t t
where exists (
    select 0
    from @t h
    where h.AccountId = t.AccountId
    group by h.AccountId
    having count(h.AccountId) > 1
);
```